Detecting fingerprint touch in Android using Dart
I want to write some code to detect when someone touches the DEVICE'S fingerprint sensor. In other words, I want to capture the attempt to log into the device from the Fingerprint Sensor.
I can find examples of using
Biometrics* classes
in Android applications. That's not what I want.
I hope someone can point me in the right direction.
I'd prefer the example using Flutter, but I really just need the algorithm.

I'd be shocked if you could, other than using the biometrics classes to authenticate yourself.  Even being able to know someone is logging in sounds like a massive security hole.

You might be right. Basically, I have an idea for a background app to take a specific action if the user touches the sensor x number of times and fails login. I know Android already does this, but I want to improve on it. (Without a new version of the OS.)
